# How to determine if EF is in Cold or Warm execution state?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, performance-testing

I'm trying to measure performance with `Stowpatch` class, including database operations, but as I understand EF performance also depends on cold and warm execution states.

I'd like to make a note on the performance log that a certain output is the result of which state EF was in at the time.

Is there a lifecycle event I could hook into or something?

Answer (score 0):

I hope [entity framework profiler](https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf) is the tool that you loking for.

Comment: Probably not, because I don't see how this would fit into an existing profiling setup. And I'm more interested in an answer to my question. Plus it costs money.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lifecycle event or anything you can hook into to determine cold vs warm query executions. According to [Performance Considerations for Entity Framework 4, 5, and 6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853(v=vs.113).aspx):

> The very first time any query is made against a given model, the
>   Entity Framework does a lot of work behind the scenes to load and
>   validate the model. We frequently refer to this first query as a
>   "cold" query.  Further queries against an already loaded model are
>   known as "warm" queries, and are much faster.

So if you want to measure performance on cold vs warm queries, execute your queries twice and use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to determine the time elapsed for the first and subsequent execution of your queries.

**First Query Execution - cold query**

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
using(var db = new MyContext())
{
    var q1 = from c in db.Customers where c.Id == 1 select c;
    var c1 = q1.First();
}
stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan coldts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

**Second Query Execution - warm query**

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
using(var db = new MyContext())
{
    var q1 = from c in db.Customers where c.Id == 1 select c;
    var c1 = q1.First();
}
stopWatch.Stop();
TimeSpan warmts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```